# ERROR 1005 (HY000) errno: 150

Tags: mysql-error-1005

I am having this problem, which has been addressed in many posts, but none of them show where I am going wrong.  I get the error 1005 with errno 150 when I try the following;

structure of appointments:

```
        CREATE TABLE `appointments` (
        `appointmentID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `apptNum` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
        `cwaID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `siteID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        `titleCode` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
        `apptPercentage` double DEFAULT '0',
        `status` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
        `payRate` double DEFAULT '0',
        `rateCode` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
        `locationInfo` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
        `apptStartDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
        `apptEndDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
        `isPrimaryAppointment` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL 
          DEFAULT 'y',
        `lastModDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE 
           CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY (`appointmentID`),
        UNIQUE KEY `appointmentID` (`appointmentID`),
        UNIQUE KEY `cwaID-apptNum` (`cwaID`,`apptNum`),
        KEY `apptNum` (`apptNum`),
        KEY `siteID` (`siteID`),
        KEY `rateCode` (`rateCode`),
        KEY `cwaID` (`cwaID`),
        KEY `titleCode` (`titleCode`),
        CONSTRAINT `FK_employees_appointments` FOREIGN KEY (`cwaID`) REFERENCES
          `employees` (`cwaID`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

structure of jobtitles:

```
    CREATE TABLE `jobtitles` (
      `titleCode` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
      `jobTitle` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
      `unitID` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
      `scope` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
      `payPeriod` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'M',
      `maxPay` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
      `minPay` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
      PRIMARY KEY (`titleCode`),
      KEY `jobTitle` (`jobTitle`),
      KEY `scope` (`scope`),
      KEY `unitID` (`unitID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to add a foreign key to appointments for the titleCode field:

```
    ALTER TABLE appointments ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_jobtitles_appointments` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`titleCode`) REFERENCES `jobtitles` (`titleCode`);
```

but this attempt generates the ERROR 1005 with errno 150, which implies a badly formed foreign key.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would expect this error if `jobtitles.titleCode` did not have an index on it.  But since this column is the primary key, it should have an index.  Are you sure that this code is really what caused the error?

Comment: Yes, I cut and pasted these snippets from the MySQL client session when I recreated the error.  The two table definitions were from a "show create table" command, and I copied and pasted the "alter table" command, which I can still reproduce:

Comment: mysql> ALTER TABLE appointments ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_jobtitles_appointments`FOREIGN KEY (`titleCode`) REFERENCES `jobtitles` (`titleCode`);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'cwa_dist6_data.#sql-b2c_47f' (errno: 150)